# How to remove contour lines during the animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.6.3 with matplotlib 2.1.0 and what I want to achieve is to be able to remove some contours which are plotted prior to animation using contour() function. 
The contour plot needs to be visible at the start of the animation and only be removed once the user presses a key. The difficulty is that I need to use blitting for the animation. Yet, blitting restores the original canvas, such that even if removing the contour it still stays visible in the blitted background.

Here is the code that shows the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from numpy import mgrid, sin, cos, pi

def keypress(event):
    if event.key == "delete":
        for c in cs.collections: c.remove() # this doesn't work
        cs.set_alpha(0.0) # this doesn't work either

phi = pi/2

def animate(i):
    global phi
    line.set_data([[0.0, sin(phi)], [0.0, cos(phi)]])
    phi += 0.01
    return line,

x,p = mgrid[-2:2:100*1j,-2:2:100*1j]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(19.2,10.8), dpi=100)
ax.set_xlim([-2,2])
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', lw=2, color='b')
cs = ax.contour(x, p, x**2 + p**2, levels=2, linewidths=0.8, colors='r')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=0, frames=2000)
plt.show()
```

If it is impossible to remove the contour, then at least I should be able to make it invisible or transparent, but I couldn't find a way to do this either. Please help! :)

Comment: After clean cycle call plt.draw()

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately all it does is that the curve which is supposed to disappear "flashes", i.e. it blinks --- disappears momentarily and then re-appears again, exactly in the same colour as it was drawn originally. I assume what you meant is to do this:
            for c in p.cs.collections: c.remove()
            plt.draw()

Comment: If your code is too large to be part of the question.. then, well, the code is too large for the question and hence not a [mcve] of the issue. If you have problems removing an artist from the canvas I'm sure it will only cost you 20 lines of code to reproduce this such that people are able to help.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question including a small test case that is only 26 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easily possible to change anything in the canvas during an animation with `blit=True` (the whole point of blitting is that the background does not change). While without the use of blit, there should not be any problem removing the lines or setting it invisible, blitting will always restore the original canvas background, even if some artist has been removed from it.

What we need to do is hence interrupt the animation after the artist removal, redraw the canvas, take a new snapshot of the background and restart the animation with a new background. While this in itself would be rather cumbersome, a possible solution is to mimic a resize event of the canvas, which would trigger exactly the described procedure. This is done in the following code.

(Note that this is working correctly with the `Qt` backend, while some problems appear using `Tk`, at least in version 2.1 of matplotlib.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from numpy import mgrid, sin, cos, pi

phi = pi/2.

def keypress(event):
    if event.key == "delete":
        try:
            for c in cs.collections: 
                c.remove()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        ani._handle_resize()
        ani._end_redraw(None)


def animate(i):
    global phi
    line.set_data([[0.0, sin(phi)], [0.0, cos(phi)]])
    phi += 0.01
    return line,

x,p = mgrid[-2:2:100*1j,-2:2:100*1j]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8,6), dpi=100)
ax.set_xlim([-2,2])
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', lw=2, color='b')
cs = ax.contour(x, p, x**2 + p**2, levels=2, linewidths=2, colors='r')

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                              blit=True, interval=1, frames=2000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but, first of all, using blit=True is absolutely essential for my application and also it is absolutely essential that the contour is removed NOT in the init() function, but at some arbitrary moment upon user's choice (e.g. pressing Del key). If I wanted to remove it in the init() I would simply not draw it in the first place :) Now, you are saying "it is not easily possible to change anything in the canvas during an animation with blit=True". Indeed, if there was an easy way I would have found it already. The question remains: is there a "not so easy" way to solve this problem?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to make that clear. I also edited the answer with a possible solution (it's a little bit of a hack, but should work nonetheless).

Comment: Thank you. Oh, that is very interesting! I will try this now and will let you know if it works...

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. What your suggestion did was: a) produce a refresh canvas upon pressing Del (i.e. everything blinked) and b) the current position of the blue line became "permanent", i.e. remained where it was, while the "real" blue line continued rotating. And if I press Del again, then I'll have _three_ blue lines (two static, one rotating) and so on.

Comment: Can you distinguish: Are you talking about the code above or are you talking about your application? Is the code above running correctly with you?

Comment: Another observation: if I resize the window or press 'f' key (for full screen) immediately after pressing Del, then the contour does disappear! So, we are _almost_ there --- we just need to fool matplotlib into thinking that a resize has occurred. Presumably that is what your call ani._handle_resize() is trying to accomplish... (Yes, I am talking about the code above. It behaves as described in this and the previous messages). Maybe we are running different versions of matplotlib if it works for you?

Comment: Also, if I try the same thing in the actual application then, after pressing Del (followed by resizing or switching to fullscreen) the contour disappears, BUT its label remains in place. The label that was placed there by cs.clabel() call. But we'll worry about the label later --- let's first make sure we can get rid of the contour...

Comment: Ok, because the code above is running perfectly fine here, I have the problem that I cannot test or debug anything. I'm having python 2.7, but that should no cause any difference. I've tested with the Qt4Agg backend in use; which one do you use?

Comment: I am using TkAgg backend, matplotlib 2.1.0, python 3.6.3. So, everything different from your setup.

Comment: It's fine, I can reproduce the described when I use TkAgg. Let's see... (although I have no idea currently ;-))

Comment: And, reciprocally, I confirm that your solution actually works with the Qt5Agg  backend (I don't have Qt4Agg). So, now I'll tick the "accept answer" as your solution really is a solution. In fact, rather than figuring out how to get it to work with TkAgg it would be more useful to figure out how to get rid of the contour labels, please :)

Comment: Got it! Just add cs.pop_label() prior to walking the cs.collection loop. It works, i.e. removes the label! Yay, we have a fully working solution. Thank you very very much! :) UPDATE: Just a minor glitch --- cs.pop_label() assumes that the contour contains a _single_ label, but there may be more than one and if so, then only one is removed. I just need to figure out how to remove the rest...

Comment: Actually, I just found that something else is really strange with the TkAgg backend. The animation is 4 to 5 times slower than using Qt, which should not be the case. So maybe that one does not lie in our hands and something went wrong at the matplotlib side of things. Glad it works for you now.

Comment: Just for completeness I should mention that the issue of removing multiple labels I have solved in a pythonic way using try/except like this: while True:
             try: self.cs.pop_label()
             except IndexError: break
Thank you very much again --- I have learnt a lot from you! :)